# Best Time to buy a stock in a day

Tags: stocks

Let's say that I want to buy a stock like MOMO and I want to buy it today (this decision was made before the market open). The duration of my position will be between a week and several month.  When should I buy the stock so that I'm nearly sure that I won't lost money in that day (because of speculation).

Comment: It should not make a difference.  You don't lose money that day.

Comment: There is no way to predict this, unless you believe that you can beat the pros in day-trading. And you believe that, I have a bridge you might be interested in buying...

Comment: I think it would be best to buy early in the day.  This will reduce your average time holding the investment before your objectives are meet.  Keep in mind there are more efficient ways to lose money.

Comment: If those that are voting to close this question can agree that "there is no best time to buy a stock in a day", then I think this is a valid question, and would not necessarily be opinion-based. If it turns into an auction of answers of "open because...", "close because...", or "midday because...", then I agree it would be a bad fit, but I don't see how that could possibly happen.

Comment: You can only lose money by selling a stock. If you don't sell that day, you won't lose.

Comment: Oh, I know the answer.  "Before you get drunk."  If you wait until after you're drunk, the odds of making an error go up dramatically.

Comment: The comment that comes to mind is that you should already know the answer to this question when you made the decision to play the market short term versus investing using a buy and hold philosophy.  If you're going to buy and hold, you buy when you make the decision.  Then you hold it until your criteria for selling are reached.  If the stock is so volatile that morning vs night makes a difference, you're engaging in highly speculative trading.  It's a gamble.  So gamble.  Flip a coin.  Go with your gut.

Comment: @TTT I would say the lowest prices after 11:54, just before noon for the NYSE and HKE, 11:09 for the LSE and 10:51 for the TSE

Comment: @keshlam: What time of day should I buy the bridge?

Comment: @brt - you will not profit if you don't sell a stock.

Comment: Look up "trailing stop buy".  It won't get you the lowest price, but it will help you get a good one ( in theory ).

Comment: @Victor It goes both ways indeed :)

Answer (score 35):

The best time to buy a stock is the time of day when the stock price is lowest!

Obviously you learned nothing from that sentence, but unfortunately you won't get a much better answer than that. Here's a question that is very similar to yours: "Is it better to have a picnic for lunch or for dinner to minimize the chance of getting rained out?" Every day is different...

Comment: I'd add to this that some research could be done. I like the picnic scenario along with it. Historically, does the rain come more often around lunch or around dinner? You can look through the history of the stock and see if it typically falls later in the day compared to opening. It's never a guarantee, but could at least be a slightly more educated decision.

Comment: @BobbyScon - I doubt that information would help very much, but I admit it probably couldn't hurt to investigate it to see if there's a pattern that is anything more than statistical noise.

Comment: I completely agree. Some stocks I own have fairly regular patterns as far as trading higher before noon, but typically by fractions of a percent. Certainly not something I'd bet against, but at least it might make you feel better about committing to a time to purchase.

Comment: @TTT, what about considering trading volume.  When there's more trading activity, don't bid-ask spreads contract a little?  I'd think a short-term trader won't want that.  If so, the trader should buy when volume is high which is probably either at the beginning or at the end of the trading day.

Comment: @user2023861 *Every day is different.*

Comment: The best time to buy is not when they are at the lowest, because most times when you buy at the lowest they will then fall lower. But if a stock is trading between a range during the day you could buy near the bottom as it bounces off the daily support. My preference is to buy after it has broken through resistance. But really the time of the day (apart from first half hour and last half hour) doesn't really matter too much.

Comment: @Victor - I agree that your strategy might help you judge when a good time to buy is, but that doesn't change the fact that you still would have been slightly better off had you bought at the lowest point rather than after it started to rise again. My answer is simply about (trivial) absolutes, not about strategy.

Comment: @TTT - how do you know when the lowest point is? Even if the stock is trading in a range, it could at any time break through support or resistance and take off. That is why if looking to buy off support you would wait for a bounce off support before you buy and place your stop just below support. If you buy as it hits support, thinking that is the low of the day, often what happens is that it breaks support and starts trading in a new range below what you bought at. Even if you bought at what was the low of the day at the close, chances are that it will open lower the next day.

Comment: @Victor - You *can't* know when it will be the "lowest" i.e. "the best time to buy", that's the point.

Comment: @TTT - you are the one that said "...but that doesn't change the fact that you still would have been slightly better off had you bought at the lowest point rather than after it started to rise again." in your previous comment above. Kind of contradicting yourself !!!

Comment: @Victor - I'm sorry if I'm explaining it poorly. Perhaps someone else can chime in and help me. I'll try one last time: If the low is $1, and shortly after that you buy at $1.01, you would have been better off buying at $1. Also, at the moment it was $1, there was no way you could have known for sure that was going to be the low, until after the fact. Where's the contradiction? A real contradiction is the first sentence of your first comment. You said if you buy at the lowest it could go lower. But if that's true then you didn't buy at the lowest...

Answer (score 12):

You can't predict when to buy a stock during the day to guarantee not having a loss for the day. In the short run stock prices are really pretty random. There are many day traders who try to accomplish exactly this and most of them lose money.

If you don't believe me, create an account on Investopedia and use their free stock market simulator and try day trading for a few months.

Answer (score 10):

One of the biggest laws in economics is that if an opportunity is very profitable and is very easily exploitable even by complete beginners, then it will very soon stop being profitable.

That's how the market works. If you buy stock when it is at the lowest, then you are making money, but most of the time someone else is losing money. And if there was a magic hour of the day when buying would be the most profitable, then soon everybody would want to buy at that time and no one would want to sell anything, so the scheme would collapse.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. The market as a whole is generally increasing over time, so there do not have to be losers. Of course there are, but it isn't a necessary condition. You can imagine a hypothetical stock which averages an increase of exactly 0.01% per day (which is pretty close to the US stock market average since 1900 after adjusting for inflation). In that case no matter when you buy, you'll always earn a modest amount, and there would be no losers.

Comment: @TTT : I agree, but the question was about a hypothetical "best time of the day" (to by stocks at a lower value than at any other time of the day), which, if existed, would be used by so may people that it would cease to be the best time of the day.

Comment: I agree with the short life of a possible best time of day, I was only disagreeing with the part of your comment that said it must be true that "someone else is losing money". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TTT While not technically accurate, I think it is *generally* appropriate to say that in day trading, winners and losers cancel out. The value of the underlying companies changes slowly over time, as corporations use investor funds to increase their businesses, leading to a net economic gain. I don't think that concept is particularly relevant to day trading, where buyers and sellers are more strictly at odds.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - I'll buy that. :D

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is not worry about what time is best to buy but put in a conditional order before the market opens. If your conditions are met during the trading day your order will go through and you will buy the shares.

This keeps your emotions out of your trading and will stop you from either chasing the market or buying when you consider the wrong time.

As you have already done your analysis and made your decision before market open, thus you should place your conditional orders and stop losses before market opens as well.

Answer (score 0):

Buy it at the close. That way you won't lose money (even if marked to market) on the day.

Comment: If you are the type of person that checks your stock quotes every 5 minutes, then buying at market close is also a good idea because you'll be able to get more work done that day. :D

Answer (score -1):

You want to buy when the stock market is at an all-time low for that day. Unfortunately, you don't know the lowest time until the end of the day, and then you, uh can't buy the stock...

Now the stock market is not random, but for your case, we can say that effectively, it is.

So, when should you buy the stock to hopefully get the lowest price for the day?

You should wait for 37% of the day, and then buy when it is lower than it has been for all of that day.

Here is a quick example (with fake data):

```
10 9 7 5 8 12 14 23 14 8 14 3 9 11 1 12 3 12
```

We have 18 points, and 37% of 18 is close to 7. So we discard the first 7 points - and just remember the lowest of those 7.

```
10 9 7 5 8 12 14 23 14 8 14 3 9 11 1 12 3 12
────────┬───────
Discard this 37%
```

We bear in mind that the lowest for the first 37% was `5`.

Now we wait until we find a stock which is lower than 5, and we buy at that point:

```
10 9 7 5 8 12 14 23 14 8 14 3 9 11 1 12 3 12
└───────┬──────┘ └──────┬─┘ | 
Discard this 37% Too High   Choose this one
```

This system is optimal for buying the stock at the lowest price for the day.

Why?

We want to find the  best position to stop automatically ignoring. Why 37%?

```
P(K) = Σ P(Being in position n) x P(Being chosen given in position n)

0 1 2 ... K K+1 K+2 ... N-1 N
```

We know the answer to `P(Being in position n)` - it's `1/N` as there are `N` toilets, and we can select just 1.

Now, what is the chance we select them, given we're in position `n`?

The chance of selecting any of the toilets from `0` to `K` is 0 - remember we're never going to buy then.

So let's move on to the toilets from K+1 and onwards. If K+1 is better than all before it, we have this:

```
P(Being in position n) = 1/N
P(Being chosen given in position n) = 1
```

But, K+1 might not be the *best* price from all past and future prices. Maybe K+2 is better. Let's look at K+2

```
P(Being in position n) = 1/N
P(Being chosen given in position n) = 1 - ( P(NOT being chosen given in position n) ) = 1 - ( 1/K+1 ) = K/K+1
```

For `K+2` we have `K/K+1`, for `K+3` we have `K/K+2`...

So we have:

```
P(K) = 1/N x 0 + 1/N x 0 + ... + 1/N x 1 + 1/N x K/K+1 + 1/N x K/K+2 + ... + 1/N x K/N-1
     = 0 + 0 + ... + (K/N) x (1/K + 1/K+1 + 1/K+2 ... + 1/N-1)
```

This is a close approximation of the area under 1/x - especially as x → ∞

[image]

```
N
∫ 1/x dx    
K

        N
= [ln(x)]
        K

= ln(N) - ln(K)

= ln(N/K)
```

So `0 + 0 + ... + (K/N) x (1/K + 1/K+1 + 1/K+2 ... + 1/N-1) ≈ (K/N) x ln(N/K)` and so `P(K) ≈ (K/N) x ln(N/K)`

Now to simplify, say that `x = K/N`

```
P(x) ≈ (x) x ln(1/x)

     ≈ -xln(x)
```

We can graph this, and find the maximum point so we know the maximum P(K) - or we can use calculus. Here's the graph:

[image]

Here's the calculus:

```
P'(K) = -ln(x) - x(1/x)
      = -ln(x) - 1

    0 = -ln(x) - 1
   -1 = ln(x)
    x = 1/e

    1/e = 1/ 2.718281828 = 0.367879441 ≈ 0.37 = 37%
```

To apply this back to your situation with the stocks, if your stock updates every 30 seconds, and is open between 09:30 and 16:00, we have 6.5 hours = 390 minutes = 780 refreshes. You should keep track of the lowest price for the first 289 refreshes, and then buy your stock on the next best price.

Because `x = K/N`, the chance of you choosing the best price is 37%. However, the chance of you choosing better than the average stock is above 50% for the day. Remember, this method just tries to mean you don't loose money within the day - if you want to try to minimise losses within the whole trading period, you should scale this up, so you wait 37% of the trading period (e.g. 37% of 3 months) and then select.

[The maths is taken from Numberphile - Mathematical Way to Choose a Toilet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWib5olGbQ0).

Finally, one way to lose money a little slower and do some good is with [Kiva.org](http://kiva.org) - giving loans to people is developing countries. It's like a bank account with a -1% interest - which is only 1% lower than a lot of banks, and you do some good. I have no affiliation with them.

Comment: You're using the secretary problem, which just doesn't apply here. For this to work you must assume that the prices during the day are sampled from some independent distribution (closer to reality is price *changes* are randomly sampled). It works because sitting back for the first 37% gives you a sense for the that assumed distribution. But you already have yesterday's information, and a super low price at midday doesn't mean a great buy because morning prices are not as relevant to afternoon prices to the extent that the current price is. I'm sorry to say, but your advice is simply wrong.

Comment: I should add though, that your answer is a very thorough and well written explanation of the secretary problem, that I do appreciate and enjoy. The downvotes don't detract from that, but simply represent that it isn't a good answer for *this* question since it doesn't apply.